# Getting TypeError using QAction

Tags: python, pyqt5

While executing following snippet of code I am getting TypeError as follows:

> TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:
>   QAction(QObject): argument 1 has unexpected type 'str'   QAction(str,
>   QObject): argument 2 has unexpected type 'Ui_MainWindow'
>   QAction(QIcon, str, QObject): argument 1 has unexpected type 'str'

Can anyone help me regrading this? I'm pretty new to this thing, Thanks in advance!!

Code snippet:

```
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        ##
        #......some more codes
        ##
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

        #app.aboutToQuit.connect(self.closeEvent)
        quit = QAction("Quit", self)
        quit.triggered.connect(self.closeEvent)

        menubar = self.menuBar()
        fmenu = menubar.addMenu("File")
        fmenu.addAction(quit)


    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        ## codes


    def closeEvent(self, event):
        choice = QtGui.QMessageBox.question(self.centralwidget,"Quit message","Are you sure you want to leave?",QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes | QtGui.QMessageBox.No)
        if choice == QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes:
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Make `Ui_MainWindow` a QObject, not an object

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more?

Comment: Replaced class Ui_MainWindow(object) with class Ui_MainWindow(QMainWindow), the Error is gone, the program is running but the closeEvent() is not working!! So I can't control the event triggered by pressing the 'X' on the window's upper right side. Please Help! Anyone??

Comment: Sorry, replace `quit = QAction("Quit", self)` with `quit = QAction("Quit", MainWindow)` instead of what I said before. The error message is pretty clear if you take the time to slog through the whole thing and read the corresponding docs.

Comment: The real problem here is that you are editing the module generated by pyuic, which is always a very bad idea. I suggest you read the pyqt docs on [how to use pyuic properly](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html#using-the-generated-code), which will fix the problem in a much more productive way.

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestion, appreciate it!!